# Product if date = specific year

Tags: excel

[image]

I am trying to compute the column M to do a product of column D if the date(column A) falls within the year as specific on column L.

So far I have tried the above formula `=PRODUCT(IF(YEAR(A4:A345)=L5,D4:D345,1))` but it failed to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you try to do it with PivotTable?

Comment: Your formula will work as an array formula confirmed with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]. After that it should appear within curly brackets like `{=PRODUCT(IF(YEAR(A4:A345)=L5,D4:D345,1))}`. But the logic is not clear to me. What shall the multiplication of returns be?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no such formula. 
One workaround I can suggest:

Create a dummy column which stores `IF(YEAR($A4) = $L4, $A4, 1)` and now apply `PRODUCT` on this column. If this report is one of your presentable reports, you can hide this column.